# Как определить есть ли полоса прокрутки у div'a?

Tags: javascript

На разных страницах есть один и тот же блок фиксированной высоты. К примеру:

```
.some_class {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

На каждой странице в данном блоке разное количество контента, по-этому в одном случае полоса прокрутки появляется, а в другом нет.

Вопрос: можно ли определить на JS, что блок имеет полосу прокрутки на определенной странице или не имеет? Если да, то как?

Comment: Что то такое помню, можно определить область видимости и размер окна, потом высчитать, но так делать точно не надо. Есть медиа запросы на CSS, кстати, попробуйте их.

Comment: А как можно на медиа запросах?

Comment: Ну я вашей задачи не знаю и не понимаю. Но если верстка зависит от ширины/высоты нужно использовать `@media` (`min-height, max-height, min-device-height, max-device-height` и пр.), а не писать костыли на JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Использовать два значения: высоту элемента и высоту прокрутки

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = (function() {
  var e = document.querySelector('.a');

  if(e.clientHeight === e.scrollHeight) 
    console.log('Полосы нет!') 
  else 
    console.log('Полоса есть!')
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.a-b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 800px;
}
input:checked ~ .a > .a-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Убрать div: <input type="checkbox">

<div class="a">
  <div class="a-b"></div>
</div>

<button>Определить</button>
```

Вариант 2. Создать вокруг ещё один элемент и измерять относительно его высоты

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = (function() {
  var e = document.querySelector('.a'),
      e_h = document.querySelector('.a2');

  if(e.clientHeight < e_h.clientHeight) 
    console.log('Полоса есть!')
  else 
    console.log('Полосы нет!') 
});
```

```css
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.a-b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 800px;
}
input:checked ~ .a .a-b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Убрать div: <input type="checkbox">

<div class="a">
  <div class="a2">
    <div class="a-b"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Определить</button>
```

Comment: ______ ______

Comment: Зачем называть объект `int`? Зачем вообще этот объект, когда можно сразу в if закинуть? А̶ ̶е̶щ̶ё̶ ̶у̶ ̶э̶т̶о̶г̶о̶ ̶с̶п̶о̶с̶о̶б̶а̶,̶ ̶к̶а̶ж̶е̶т̶с̶я̶,̶ ̶е̶с̶т̶ь̶ ̶о̶г̶р̶а̶н̶и̶ч̶е̶н̶и̶е̶ ̶н̶а̶ ̶p̶a̶d̶d̶i̶n̶g̶'̶и̶,̶ ̶к̶о̶т̶о̶р̶о̶е̶ ̶н̶е̶ ̶у̶п̶о̶м̶я̶н̶у̶т̶о̶ ̶в̶ ̶о̶т̶в̶е̶т̶е̶?̶  UPDATE: С паддингами всё хорошо, это я что-то намудрил.